# What Kinds Of Mathematics Are Required For A Data Compressor?

Tags: c++, math, compression

What kinds of mathematics are required to program a data compressor (C++)? Are there any specific branches of calculus required? How are these implemented?

Comment: Combinatorics & probability are probably needed. But your question is off-topic here, better on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read [Elements of Information Theory](http://www.elementsofinformationtheory.com/) by Thomas M. Cover and Joy A. Thomas. This answers your questions on a funded theoretical basis.

Comment: I'd like to apologize for that, the intention was clear: it's the first authors name ;) Anyway ... now both authors are there.

Answer (score 1):

I would say mostly [*information theory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory) and [*statistics*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics).

Of course basic math and logic knowledge is required, but this is true for programming algorithms in general.